# Fetch data after and before '_' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I got the following entry in my database:

```
I_ABC_2000.txt
```

I want to trim the entry so I get: `ABC`

So basically, I want everything after the first `_`  and before the 2nd  `_` .

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You go to the SQL Server reference docs, find the string functions section, and see which functions would help you accomplish this task.

Comment: Also, could a value have more than 2 `_` characters, or will it always be 2?

Comment: it can have more than 2_

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly better ways to do this.. but one that I use is to use a scalar function . 
Create a scalar function and then call that function over your string

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseString]
(
    @Section SMALLINT,
    @Delimiter CHAR,
    @Text varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextPos SMALLINT,
        @LastPos SMALLINT,
        @Found SMALLINT

    IF @Section > 0
        SELECT  @Text = REVERSE(@Text)

    SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1),
        @LastPos = 0,
        @Found = 1

    WHILE @NextPos > 0 AND ABS(@Section) <> @Found
        SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos,
            @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1),
            @Found = @Found + 1

    RETURN  CASE
            WHEN @Found <> ABS(@Section) OR @Section = 0 THEN NULL
            WHEN @Section > 0 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)
        END
END
```

Then you can call the function over your text (the first argument is the position of the text you want, the second is the delimiter of your text and the thirst is the actual text)

```
select dbo.[fnParseString] (1,'_','abra_ka_dabra')
```

would return

> dabra

select dbo.[fnParseString] (2,'_','abra_ka_dabra')

would return

> ka

etc.